# Does the await automatically dispose the StreamReader resource in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, garbage-collection, dispose

Does it make sense to use the `using` pattern in this case? Or does `await` automatically dispose of this resource?

```
var payload = await new StreamReader(HttpContext.Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
```

Comment: You still want to dispose this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, and why would it?

Look at the whole StreamReader API - it i s not ONLY "ReadToEnd" - and even then, what if your code then RESETS the reader to a different position and reads more?

It would totally go against the API of a StreamReader to automatically dispose it and actively sabotage it in many use cases.

Also, it would make an async method behave different form the non-async version.

Ergo - no, it does make no sense for it to dispose, so it does not.

Comment: It is actually even impossible for `await` to dispose (or act in any other way) on an object that *happen to be* used on the same line as await itself - the only thing `await` can see in this particular case is `Task<string>` - there is absolutely no connection to the stream that was used to create the task... (indeed Task itself is disposable... due to technical reasons but one neither expected to dispose those nor it would impact underlying stream - https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/do-i-need-to-dispose-of-tasks/)

Comment: This is not technically true. The method called can dispose before returning - i.e. when it returns, the stream is disposed. The Dispose would have to happen IN the called method.

Answer (score 1):

No, await does no such thing.

But it makes sense to wrap streams that your code creates in a `using() { ... }` or a `try/finally` block, Yes.  However, if the stream was not "created" by your code then you should feel no obligation to dispose or close it.

You could easily do this:

```
using (StreamReader s = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Request.Body))
{
    var payload = await s.ReadToEndAsync();
}
```

Comment: *"The main thing the `await` does is return the calling thread back into the main worker pool"* -- In case the calling thread is the UI thread, it is certainly not returned back into the `ThreadPool`.

Comment: true, i am mostly referring to web calls.  I will update my answer.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias This is an ASP application, so it is in fact a thread pool thread in this specific case.  But it isn't necessarily in the general case.

Comment: If this code was executed in web with no prior Task/WorkerThread invoking it, then it is ThreadPool.

Comment: I am seeing the updated answer ([revision 5](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77054450/5)). What does the `await` do in console applications? What does the `await` do in windows service applications? I think that trying to explain the `await` by application type is a lost cause. Explaining it in an application agnostic way is better IMHO.

Comment: I get it... i was trying to point out that await/async have nothing to do with IDispose.  I will remove the comment tho.

Comment: @Servy yes, the `HttpContext.Request.Body` indicates that the OP is working with an ASP.NET application. The question though is presented in an application agnostic way. The OP asks about the `await` in C# in general. The question is not decorated with any ASP.NET-related tag.